# библиотека Reqests и TOR

Tags: python, requests, tor

На компьютере установлен и работает Tor browser,т.е. мост установлен и страницы открываются.

Служба работает:

```
ko-1@ko-1-Lenovo-G570:~$ sudo service tor status  
● tor.service - Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (multi-instance-master)  
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/tor.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)  
     Active: active (exited) since Sun 2022-02-20 15:29:13 MSK; 13min ago
```

Он слушает порт по умолчанию:

```
ko-1@ko-1-Lenovo-G570:~$ sudo lsof -i :9050  
COMMAND PID       USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME  
tor     676 debian-tor    6u  IPv4  27878      0t0  TCP localhost:9050 (LISTEN)
```

при попытке выполнить get запрос:

```
import requests
proxies = {
    'http': 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9050',
    'https': 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9050'
}
try:
    res = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/ip', timeout=10, proxies=proxies)
    print(res)
except Exception as Err:
    print(Err)
```

получаю ошибку `<class 'requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout'>`

как будто трафик не идет через порт.

пакет PySocks установлен и если выбрать рабочий прокси то все ок.В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Когда ходил через tor, уставливал еще `pip install -U requests[socks]`: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/5f333adc169490c9d3d031f929f00c3a9e222ed9/using_tor/load_onion__using_socks5h.py#L20

Comment: requests[socks] сейчас наверное входит в Pysocks , мне пишет уже установлено